# Java Swing - JButton wrong border

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

I try to set new red border to my "Ok" button, but instead of [image: this1] I get [image: this2] from [image: this] this. How to make 1-st picture? (it's photoshop)

I try

```
button.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overrided the button's default border. You should set a compound border using the existing one and a new red one.

```
Border innerBorder = button.getBorder();
Border outerBorder = new LineBorder(Color.RED, 1);
button.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(outerBorder, innerBorder));
```

Here is a one liner combined with using the BorderFactory :-)

```
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1),
    button.getBorder()));
```

Using BorderFactory - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#createapi